# How do I show 2 images on row 1 and 3 images underneath on row 2 with Views?

Tags: 7, views

I need to create a page on my Drupal website which shows colleague images (colleague profile pics).

I want to position 2 colleagues pics next to each other on row 1 then underneath show 3 images on row 2, as shown in this picture:

[image]

I have set up a content type called **Colleagues**, which has fields of `Title` and `Image`. And I have set up a View to read that content and display the images, and the title underneath.

I can display them in whatever order I need, but how do I display them so that there are 2 at top and 3 underneath?

The only way I can think of is to add a field called Row Number, and create 2 Views for each row and display them accordingly, but that seems messy.

Can anyone help?

Comment: This is a CSS issue and you can use nth selectors etc. Else do it in the Views template where on the row count you would open or close one of the two wrapping divs.

Comment: ok, i will ask on the Stackoverflow site

Answer (score 1):

You can define attachment display of view, in which u can display only 2 images with offset 0 under Pager section. and in page you can define image to show as 3, with offset as 2.

As attachment loads above the page, so it will show the structure accordingly.

Comment: Easiest and best solution. Modifying theme files for a simple issue just causes hassle if more than one person is working at it.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could get what you want by modifying the theming files for your specific view.

If you go to your view edit page, in **Advanced** >> **Other** >> **Theme: information** you can take a look at which files are being used to construct your view.

Then, if you look at the *Style output* default file, you can see how the table is being made.

You can implement your own template for the table, by adding the corresponding file *views-view-table--your-view-name--displayname.tpl.php* to your module/theme folder.